# pd.merge_asof with multiple matches per time period?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes by time with  multiple matches. I'm looking for all the instances of df2 whose `timestamp` falls 7 days or less before `endofweek` in df1. There may be more than one record that fits the case, and I want all of the matches, not just the first or last (which pd.merge_asof does).

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'endofweek': ['2019-08-31', '2019-08-31', '2019-09-07', '2019-09-07', '2019-09-14', '2019-09-14'], 'GroupCol': [1234,8679,1234,8679,1234,8679]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2019-08-30 10:00', '2019-08-30 10:30', '2019-09-07 12:00', '2019-09-08 14:00'], 'GroupVal': [1234, 1234, 8679, 1234], 'TextVal': ['1234_1', '1234_2', '8679_1', '1234_3']})
df1['endofweek'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['endofweek'])
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])
```

I've tried

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7d'), direction='backward', left_on='endofweek', right_on='timestamp', left_by='GroupCol', right_by='GroupVal')
```

but that gets me

```
   endofweek  GroupCol           timestamp  GroupVal TextVal
0 2019-08-31      1234 2019-08-30 10:30:00    1234.0  1234_2
1 2019-08-31      8679                 NaT       NaN     NaN
2 2019-09-07      1234                 NaT       NaN     NaN
3 2019-09-07      8679                 NaT       NaN     NaN
4 2019-09-14      1234 2019-09-08 14:00:00    1234.0  1234_3
5 2019-09-14      8679 2019-09-07 12:00:00    8679.0  8679_1
```

I'm losing the text 1234_1. Is there way to do a sort of outer join for `pd.merge_asof`, where I can keep all of the instances of `df2` and not just the first or last?

My ideal result would look like this (assuming that the `endofweek` times are treated like 00:00:00 on that date):

```
   endofweek  GroupCol           timestamp  GroupVal TextVal
0 2019-08-31      1234 2019-08-30 10:00:00    1234.0  1234_1
1 2019-08-31      1234 2019-08-30 10:30:00    1234.0  1234_2
2 2019-08-31      8679                 NaT       NaN     NaN
3 2019-09-07      1234                 NaT       NaN     NaN                 
4 2019-09-07      8679                 NaT       NaN     NaN 
5 2019-09-14      1234 2019-09-08 14:00:00    1234.0  1234_3
6 2019-09-14      8679 2019-09-07 12:00:00    8679.0  8679_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge_asof` only does a left join. After a lot of frustration trying to speed up the `groupby`/`merge_ordered` example, it's more intuitive and faster to do `pd.merge_asof` on both data sources in different directions, and then do an outer join to combine them.

```py
left_merge = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2,
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7d'), direction='backward', 
    left_on='endofweek', right_on='timestamp', 
    left_by='GroupCol', right_by='GroupVal')

right_merge = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, 
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7d'), direction='forward', 
    left_on='timestamp', right_on='endofweek',
    left_by='GroupVal', right_by='GroupCol')

merged = (left_merge.merge(right_merge, how="outer")
    .sort_values(['endofweek', 'GroupCol', 'timestamp'])
    .reset_index(drop=True))

merged

   endofweek  GroupCol           timestamp  GroupVal TextVal
0 2019-08-31      1234 2019-08-30 10:00:00    1234.0  1234_1
1 2019-08-31      1234 2019-08-30 10:30:00    1234.0  1234_2
2 2019-08-31      8679                 NaT       NaN     NaN
3 2019-09-07      1234                 NaT       NaN     NaN
4 2019-09-07      8679                 NaT       NaN     NaN
5 2019-09-14      1234 2019-09-08 14:00:00    1234.0  1234_3
6 2019-09-14      8679 2019-09-07 12:00:00    8679.0  8679_1
```

In addition, it is much faster than my other answer:

```py
import time
n=1000
start=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    left_merge = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2,
        tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7d'), direction='backward', 
        left_on='endofweek', right_on='timestamp', 
        left_by='GroupCol', right_by='GroupVal')
    right_merge = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, 
        tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7d'), direction='forward', 
        left_on='timestamp', right_on='endofweek',
        left_by='GroupVal', right_by='GroupCol')
    merged = (left_merge.merge(right_merge, how="outer")
        .sort_values(['endofweek', 'GroupCol', 'timestamp'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))

end = time.time()

end-start
15.040804386138916
```

Comment: This will still only work when the max. amount of matches between df1 and df2 is 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

One way I tried is using `groupby` on one data frame, and then subsetting the other one in a `pd.merge_ordered`:

```
merged = (df1.groupby(['GroupCol', 'endofweek']).
apply(lambda x: pd.merge_ordered(x, df2[(
(df2['GroupVal']==x.name[0])
&(abs(df2['timestamp']-x.name[1])<=pd.Timedelta('7d')))], 
left_on='endofweek', right_on='timestamp')))

merged

                       endofweek  GroupCol           timestamp  GroupVal TextVal
GroupCol endofweek
1234     2019-08-31 0        NaT       NaN 2019-08-30 10:00:00    1234.0  1234_1
                    1        NaT       NaN 2019-08-30 10:30:00    1234.0  1234_2
                    2 2019-08-31    1234.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
         2019-09-07 0 2019-09-07    1234.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
         2019-09-14 0        NaT       NaN 2019-09-08 14:00:00    1234.0  1234_3
                    1 2019-09-14    1234.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
8679     2019-08-31 0 2019-08-31    8679.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
         2019-09-07 0 2019-09-07    8679.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
         2019-09-14 0        NaT       NaN 2019-09-07 12:00:00    8679.0  8679_1
                    1 2019-09-14    8679.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN

merged[['endofweek', 'GroupCol']] = (merged[['endofweek', 'GroupCol']]
.fillna(method="bfill"))

merged.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

merged
   endofweek  GroupCol           timestamp  GroupVal TextVal
0 2019-08-31    1234.0 2019-08-30 10:00:00    1234.0  1234_1
1 2019-08-31    1234.0 2019-08-30 10:30:00    1234.0  1234_2
2 2019-08-31    1234.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
3 2019-09-07    1234.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
4 2019-09-14    1234.0 2019-09-08 14:00:00    1234.0  1234_3
5 2019-09-14    1234.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
6 2019-08-31    8679.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
7 2019-09-07    8679.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
8 2019-09-14    8679.0 2019-09-07 12:00:00    8679.0  8679_1
9 2019-09-14    8679.0                 NaT       NaN     NaN
```

However it seems to me the result is very slow:

```
import time
n=1000
start=time.time()
for i in range(n):
    merged = (df1.groupby(['GroupCol', 'endofweek']).
    apply(lambda x: pd.merge_ordered(x, df2[(
    (df2['GroupVal']==x.name[0])
    &(abs(df2['timestamp']-x.name[1])<=pd.Timedelta('7d')))], 
    left_on='endofweek', right_on='timestamp')))

end = time.time()

end-start
40.72932052612305
```

I would greatly appreciate any improvements!