# Efficient way to merge large Pandas dataframes between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know there are many questions like this one but I can't seem to find the relevant answer.
Let's say I have 2 data frames as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "end": [
            "2019-08-31",
            "2019-08-28",
            "2019-09-09",
            "2019-09-08",
            "2019-09-14",
            "2019-09-14",
        ],
        "start": [
            "2019-08-27",
            "2019-08-22",
            "2019-08-04",
            "2019-09-02",
            "2019-09-06",
            "2019-09-10",
        ],
        "id": [1234, 8679, 8679, 1234, 1234, 8679],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            "2019-08-30 10:00",
            "2019-08-28 10:00",
            "2019-08-27 10:30",
            "2019-08-07 12:00",
            "2019-09-12 10:00",
            "2019-09-11 14:00",
            "2019-08-29 18:00",
        ],
        "id": [1234, 1234, 8679, 1234, 8679, 8679, 1234],
        "val": ["AAAB", "ABBA", "CXXC", "BBAA", "XCXC", "CCXX", "BAAB"],
    }
)

df1["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["end"])
df1["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["start"])

df2["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["timestamp"])

df1.sort_values(by=["end"], inplace=True)
df2.sort_values(by="timestamp", inplace=True)
```

Resulted as:

```py
 end       start    id
0  2019-08-31  2019-08-27  1234
1  2019-08-28  2019-08-22  8679
2  2019-09-09  2019-08-04  8679
3  2019-09-08  2019-09-02  1234
4  2019-09-14  2019-09-06  1234
5  2019-09-14  2019-09-10  8679

 timestamp    id   val
0  2019-08-30 10:00  1234  AAAB
1  2019-08-28 10:00  1234  ABBA
2  2019-08-27 10:30  8679  CXXC
3  2019-08-07 12:00  1234  BBAA
4  2019-09-12 10:00  8679  XCXC
5  2019-09-11 14:00  8679  CCXX
6  2019-08-29 18:00  1234  BAAB
```

The classic way to merge by ID so timestamp will be between start and end in df1 is by merge on id or dummy variable and filter:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on="id")
merged_df = merged_df.loc[
    (merged_df["timestamp"] >= merged_df["start"])
    & (merged_df["timestamp"] <= merged_df["end"])
]
```

In which I get the output I wish to have:

```
           end       start    id         timestamp   val
0   2019-08-31  2019-08-27  1234  2019-08-30 10:00  AAAB
1   2019-08-31  2019-08-27  1234  2019-08-28 10:00  ABBA
3   2019-08-31  2019-08-27  1234  2019-08-29 18:00  BAAB
4   2019-08-28  2019-08-22  8679  2019-08-27 10:30  CXXC
7   2019-09-09  2019-08-04  8679  2019-08-27 10:30  CXXC
19  2019-09-14  2019-09-10  8679  2019-09-12 10:00  XCXC
20  2019-09-14  2019-09-10  8679  2019-09-11 14:00  CCXX
```

**My question:** I need to do the same merge and get the same results but df1 is 200K rows and df2 is 600K.

What I have tried so far:

- The classic way of merge and filter, as above, will fail because the initial merge will create a huge data frame that will overload the memory.
- I also tried the pandasql approach which ended with my 16GB RAM PC
  getting stuck.
- I tried the merge_asof in 3 steps of left join, right join and outer join as
  explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810517/pd-merge-asof-with-multiple-matches-per-time-period) but I run some tests and it seems to always
  return up to 2 records from df2 to a single line in df1.

Any good advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Since you only care about a specific subset and not the whole dataframe, have you tried filtering first on df1 and df2 and then use the left merge/join/whatever? I guess it will work if your  range is not the whole dataframe. I guess you don't really need to merge the whole dataframe if you only want a subset.

Comment: Do the intervals overlap? Interval index should do it, however with overlapping indices, it might be a bit tricky

Comment: oh one other thing, are there duplicates in df2?

Comment: in df2 there are no duplicates, but several incidents in df2 can fit a single record in df1.  as you can see indexes 0,1,3 in the output example

Comment: why dont you dump it into sql and run it? or use python's pypolar library, or R's data.table (they have support of non-equi joins, which is quite efficient as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with [niv-dudovitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7836972/niv-dudovitch) and [david-arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) on this one, and here are our findings which I hope will be helpful to some of you out there...
The core idea was to prevent growing objects in memory by creating a list of dataframes based on subsets of the data.

### First version without multi-processing.

```py
import pandas as pd

unk = df1.id.unique()
j = [None] * len(unk)
k = 0

df1.set_index('id', inplace = True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace = True)

for i in unk:
    tmp = df1.loc[df1.index.isin([i])].join(df2.loc[df2.index.isin([i])], how='left')  
    j[k] = tmp.loc[tmp['timestamp'].between(tmp['start'], tmp['end'])]
    k += 1
    
res = pd.concat(j)
res
```

### Using Multi-Process

In our real case, we have 2 large data frame df2 is about 3 million rows and df1 is slightly above 110K. The output is about 20M rows.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools
import concurrent
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
import pandas as pd
from itertools import repeat


def get_val_between(ids, df1, df2):
    """
    Locate all values between 2 dates by id
    Args:
        - ids (list): list of ids

    Returns:
        - concat list of dataframes
    """

    j = [None] * len(ids)
    k = 0

    for i in ids:
        tmp = df1.loc[df1.index.isin([i])].join(
            df2.loc[df2.index.isin([i])], how="left"
        )
        tmp = tmp.loc[tmp["timestamp"].between(tmp["start"], tmp["end"])]

        # add to list in location k

        j[k] = tmp
        k += 1
    # keep only not None dfs in j

    j = [i for i in j if i is not None]
    if len(j) > 0:
        return pd.concat(j)
    else:
        return None


def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    """grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"""

    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


def main():

    df1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    id_lst = df1.id.unique()
    iter_ids = grouper(10, list(id_lst))

    df1.set_index("id", inplace=True)
    df2.set_index("id", inplace=True)

    # set multi-processes

    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(20)
    result_futures = executor.map(get_val_between, iter_ids, repeat(df1), repeat(df2))
    concurrent.futures.as_completed(result_futures)
    result_concat = pd.concat(result_futures)

    print(result_concat)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

results as expected:

```
           end      start           timestamp   val
id                                                  
8679 2019-08-28 2019-08-22 2019-08-27 10:30:00  CXXC
8679 2019-09-09 2019-08-04 2019-08-27 10:30:00  CXXC
8679 2019-09-14 2019-09-10 2019-09-11 14:00:00  CCXX
8679 2019-09-14 2019-09-10 2019-09-12 10:00:00  XCXC
1234 2019-08-31 2019-08-27 2019-08-28 10:00:00  ABBA
1234 2019-08-31 2019-08-27 2019-08-29 18:00:00  BAAB
1234 2019-08-31 2019-08-27 2019-08-30 10:00:00  AAAB
```

As a benchmark with an output of 20 million rows, the Multi-Process approach is x10 times faster.

Comment: would appreciate if you've got some sample data that i can play with

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can make a function with `groupby` and find the matching date range with `pd.IntervalIndex` so you don't have to `merge`:

```
def func():
    for x, y in df2.groupby("id"):
        tmp = df1.loc[df1["id"].eq(x)]
        tmp.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(tmp['start'], tmp['end'], closed='both')
        y[["start", "end"]] = tmp.loc[y.timestamp, ["start", "end"]].to_numpy()
        yield y

print (pd.concat(func()).sort_index())

            timestamp    id   val      start        end
0 2019-08-30 10:00:00  1234  AAAB 2019-08-27 2019-08-31
1 2019-08-28 10:00:00  1234  ABBA 2019-08-27 2019-08-31
2 2019-08-07 10:30:00  8679  CXXC 2019-08-04 2019-09-09
3 2019-08-27 12:00:00  1234  BBAA 2019-08-27 2019-08-31
4 2019-09-12 10:00:00  8679  XCXC 2019-09-10 2019-09-14
5 2019-09-11 14:00:00  8679  CCXX 2019-09-10 2019-09-14
6 2019-08-29 18:00:00  1234  BAAB 2019-08-27 2019-08-31
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems like a good approach but I can't seem to make it work on my 'real' data. I keep  having a general "key error"  in this line: ```y[["start", "end"]]```